# YouTube API - video plays, but functions like playVideo and seekTo don't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, internet-explorer-9

My site uses the YouTube API to embed a video, and relies on being able to use Javascript to play, pause, and seek through the video.

Currently, the site works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE10. However, I have problems in IE9.

In IE9, the video player correctly plays. However, the player object is somehow corrupted.

When the video is playing, player.getPlayerState() should return 1. When the video is paused, player.getPlayerState() should return 2. This is indeed correct in FF, Chrome, and IE10.

However, in IE9, player.getPlayerState() returns -1 regardless of whether it is playing or stopped. In addition player.playVideo() and player.pauseVideo() do not seem to do anything.

What's interesting is even in IE8, the player.getPlayerState(), player.playVideo(), player.pauseVideo() work fine. It's ONLY in IE9 that the problem exists.

I would appreciate any relevant information or ideas as to where to debug this problem. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to update, I've tested this on a separate (friend's) machine, too.

============================

Here is an external link to the site in question, for visual reference.

http://tabless.net/tabs/50/t/Blink-182-All-The-Small-Things/

To test, just click the play button to toggle play/pause. Or you can use spacebar.